# Padding not working

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, margins

So I was recommended not to use tables for my layout and I tried that and it's giving me this annoying problem of not working the way I want it to.

Here's my final result that I currently have:
[image: Final result of code.]

However, I want to move that hello in the bottom right box to the same left margin/padding as the text in Home right above it.

Here's my code.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two');
#Cogna {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 40px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two';
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 4em 1em 1em 1em;
}

.maintext {
  padding: 1.58em;
  height: 46em;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-width: 80%;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 40px 20px 10px 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 20%;
  height: 46em;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="Cogna">Cogna</div>
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <nav>
    <ul>Home</ul>
    <ul>a</ul>
    <ul>a</ul>
    <ul>a</ul>
    <ul>a</ul>
    <ul>a</ul>
    <ul>a</ul>
    <ul>a</ul>
    <span style="display: block; height: 100%;"></span>
  </nav>
  <div class="maintext">
    <p style="margin-left: 16pt;">
      Hello.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I can't seem to properly accomplish that task. I've change the margin and padding of both the nav and the `maintext` id in my CSS to and it still won't seem to budge. I then tried a variety of display style changes (though not all, as I'm new to CSS and idk which one would do the job). Most of them didn't seem to work.

Also, if anyone could reduce that gap between the top two boxes and the bottom two, that would also be great, but not entirely necessary.

The div element `maintext` should capture all the paragraphs in the bottom-left box, so I want all of the text in that element to have that padding.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: That's because `<nav>` is floated to the left and `<div class="maintext">` is not. `#maintext` actually extends behind `<nav>` but the content of `#maintext` does not. The content _"reacts"_ to the floated element. You will need to float `#mainttext`. You will also need to adjust margins/and padding as they will be added to your percentage widths. You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` for those elements so width values will include padding and borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add `box-sizing: border-box` to `nav` and `.maintext`, then add `width: 80%; overflow: auto;` to `.maintext` to get it to sit beside `nav`, then just use the same padding `.maintext` as you applied to the `h1` if you want it to match that padding.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two');
#Cogna {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 40px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two';
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 4em 1em 1em 1em;
}

.maintext {
  padding: 1.58em;
  height: 46em;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 40px 20px 10px 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 20%;
  height: 46em;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav, .maintext {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cogna</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div id="Cogna">Cogna</div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <nav>
        <ul>Home</ul>
        <ul>a</ul>
        <ul>a</ul>
        <ul>a</ul>
        <ul>a</ul>
        <ul>a</ul>
        <ul>a</ul>
        <ul>a</ul>
        <span style="display: block; height: 100%;"></span>
    </nav>
    <div class="maintext">
        <p style="margin-left: 16pt;">
            Hello.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost gets me what I want. Though, this kind of made my navigation width smaller - any way to fix that?

Comment: @OsamaKawish yeah, the width will change because I used `box-sizing: border-box;` - just update the width of `nav` and `.maintext` to be the actual width you want them.